# Hibernate sql grammar exception when query has too long insert parameter

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

have a method in which i try to do update operation;

```
public boolean formVeriGuncelleSil(String sql) throws VeritabaniException {
        try {
            Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
            query.executeUpdate();
            return true;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw new VeritabaniException(e, VERIGUNCELLEMEEXCEPTION, "FID_01_02_01");
        }
    }
```

**The sql string**

```
UPDATE K1FORM_LISTGRID3 SET TEXTAREA4='X', TEXTT5='ANAFORM',ANATABLO='1', OLUSTURAN_KULLANICI='184' WHERE ID=1
```

if X is very long string, i have this exception;

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
```

if X is normal string there is no exception.

The exception arise from X string, if X is too long.

I have searched for, but i don't find any solution. Pls help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work around is to set a long length for your `TEXTAREA4`.

You can use `blob` instead of `String` if your input is a file's contents. I believe that has no such boundaries as string when trying to bulk update.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I converted string value to clob, but how can i use this value in my native sql. Briefly, how can i insert clob value to table? This is my new problem now :S

Comment: It is another question, worth asking. You might find how to use these types in your program. If not, you better ask it in SO.

Comment: You can have a `File` stored in DB using `blob`. This is a brief hint, which I hope to be useful for you. Search how to store file in DB and you'll see lots of examples. Clear enough?

Answer (score -1):

Call `createQuery()` instead of `createSQLQuery()`.

```
SQLQuery query = session.createQuery(sql);
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried this but i got this error now  'org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: K1FORM_LISTGRID3 is not mapped'

Comment: It is now a mapping issue. Please check your table mappings.

Comment: `createQuery()` creates an HQL query. Changing to this, does not help.